# How do I parse through my firebase data with children in swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Swift 4.0 Xcode9

I would like to get just the title of the job description and populate my tableView with it. I have tried so many ways but I cannot get it to work because the "child" in my code has no members. I can print it but that is it.

When I print my data to console it looks like the attached image. So I am getting data.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
{

@IBOutlet weak var jobPostsTableView: UITableView!


//Set the Firebase Reference
var ref = Database.database().reference()

var searchJSONQuery : String = ""

var jobsData = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jobsData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = jobsData[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}


func retrieveJobTitles() {

    let positionRef = ref.child("positions")

    positionRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // Iterate through all of your positions
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let positionsInfo = child.value as! [String: Any]

            let jobTitle = positionsInfo["title"] as! String

            if jobTitle != nil {
                self.jobsData.append(jobTitle)
            }
        }

        self.jobPostsTableView.reloadData()


    })
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    jobPostsTableView.delegate = self
    jobPostsTableView.dataSource = self

    retrieveJobTitles()


}
}
```

the child.value gives an error:

```
Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'
```

Comment: `child` you may need to cast `child` into something else that corresponds to the class where it has a property `value` so you can do `child.value`. Else, it is casted by default to `Any`.

Comment: You were right. I had to cast child..
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your database JSON structure should look similar to this

[image]

First thing I do is create an NSObject class that will basically hold all the values from my database. In this example, I want to parse the `date`, `message`, and `name`

```
class MyObjects: NSObject {

var date: AnyObject!
var message: AnyObject!
var name: AnyObject!

}
```

In your TableViewController class, create a an instance of your NSObject class then create a function that will retrieve your data from firebase.

`var myObject = [MyObject]()`

```
 func retrieveData() {

    Database.datanase().reference().child("todo").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in 

            let dict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
            let object = MyObject()
            object.setValuesForKeys(dict)
            self.myObject(object)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })    
    })


    }
```

And to use it, just do `myObject.date`, `myObject.name`, `myObject.message`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your solution as well